# Is there any way to show amount of missed Empathy messages in the launcher icon?

Tags: unity, launcher, empathy

I use Empathy and I have a problem with notifications for non read messages.

Is there any way to show amount of missed messages at left panel icon, like Thunderbird, SkypeWrapper, .... and other applications.

Empathy is a default massager in Ubuntu :) ,.... I did not find any related settings in Empathy preferences.

Comment: I found workaround that ease the problem - is to show it in top panel as indicator, for this you  need to install "sudo apt-get install dconf-tools" launch it as "dconf-editor" and add ",'empathy'" to "desktop.unity.panel.systray-whitelist". Do logout and login. Icon will blink on top for new/unread messages.

Answer (score 1):

You can use [Unity Mail](https://apps.ubuntu.com/cat/applications/unity-mail/) for notifications in a launcher. You can set it to open Empathy when you click it. And Empathy had a notifications plugin, which I haven't used and don't knowhow to install/enable it.

Answer (score 1):

There is also an option to do that for Ubuntu 13.10: you have to do some additional magic to let systray-whitelist to appear in dconf-editor )

[See here](http://linuxg.net/how-to-restore-the-systray-whitelist-on-ubuntu-13-04/)